# How to be notified when received changes from only the remote CloudKit database?

Tags: ios, core-data, cloudkit

I'm building an app with Core Data and CloudKit. I need to detect when remote changes have been pushed to the app and are available in the local database to perform some work on the new data set. I've implemented `.NSPersistentStoreRemoteChange` like so:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.storeRemoteChange(_:)), name: .NSPersistentStoreRemoteChange, object: container.persistentStoreCoordinator)
```

The problem is this notification is received even when changes haven't been received from the remote CloudKit database, such as 4 times when the app is launched, and when a modification is made to the local database. How can I know only when changes have been received from the remote database?

Comment: I have only used CKContainer, not the new NSPersistentCloudKitContainer. Does it fire a push notification when you get changes like it does with CKContainer?  In AppDelegate application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)?  That would be a way to tell.

Comment: @BrianM That is deprecated, but neither that nor the new API (`userNotificationCenter(_:willPresent:withCompletionHandler:)`) are called.

Answer (score 1):

While I wasn't able to detect only this scenario, I did accomplish my needs by utilizing `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` and performing both remote and local change processing when this notification is triggered.

Answer (score 1):

This was added in iOS 14

[NSPersistentCloudKitContainer.eventChangedNotification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentcloudkitcontainer/3618808-eventchangednotification)
[NSPersistentCloudKitContainer.EventType.import](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentcloudkitcontainer/eventtype/import)